# Create boxplot from 5-point-summary

Tags: plot, graph, charts, gnuplot, boxplot

How do I create a boxplot when I am given just the 5-point summary (min, 1st quartile, median, 3rd quartile, max) but don't have the data itself?

I cannot simply pretend these 5 points are all I have and plot them because if I do, my min/max sometimes get treated as outliers.

Comment: `plot ... using candlesticks whiskerbars`, see last example at http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/candlesticks.html

Comment: @Christoph worked, thank you. (but that site would be a lot more useful if it contained the data they used). Do you want to make an answer out of it?